# SSRS: =MID and InStr

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to `SSRS` and expression, so please bear with me.

I want to be able to extract and capture certain data in a string text, for example:

- Added Table 'Yellow-Red-White' to 'abc abc - [abc] xxx ....
- Deleted Table 'Yellow-Blue-Red' from 'abc abc - [abc] xxx ....

I just want to capture anything after **Table '** and before **'to** or **' from**

This is what I have so far,

```
=MID(Fields!Table.Value,InStr(Fields!Table.Value,"Yellow-")
,LEN(TRIM(Fields!Table.Value))-InStr(Fields!Table.Value,"' to",)-6)
```

When I runs this, it would returns **Yellow-Blue-Red' from 'abc abc - [abc] xxx...**
How can I take off anything that after **' from** or **' to**? The characters at the **' to** or **' from** is not always the same and not always same # of characters, one row can be less another row can be more. The only thing that the same/repeat is the 
**Added Table
Deleted Table **

Greatly appreciate any help out there.

JT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two similar options:

1. Do all the work in an SSRS Expression as you are currently doing:

I would replace both the 'from' and 'to' parts of the string to a single identifier string and then look for that.
I can't check this at the moment but basically you need to swap out any reference to `Fields!Table.Value` with

```
Replace(Replace(Fields!Table.Value," to ","#findme#")," from ","#findme#")
```

Also, you need to look for occurrences of 'Table', not 'Yellow' and adjust the expression accordingly, the start point position of your MID expression would have to be adjusted to take the length of the string 'Table' into account.

The expressions can get a but messy to read so I often prefer to take another approach as follows.

Option 2:
Do some or all of the work in your dataset, this will make the report easier to understand. The process will be similar except you would create a new column in the dataset and modify the SQL to pull out the correct part of your Table column.

Something like this

```
SELECT 
   myTableColumn
   [my other columns]....,
   , SUBSTRING(myTableColumn
                ,  CHARINDEX('table ', myTableColumn) + 6
                , CHARINDEX(' #findme# ',REPLACE(REPLACE(myTableColumn, ' from ', ' #findme# '), ' to ', ' #findme# ')) 
                    - CHARINDEX('table ', myTableColumn) - 6) as myResult
FROM myTable
```

Comment: thank you so much Canadean_AS! the second option seem to work better!